# How to fix NullPointerException "org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils.JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VERSION_AS_ENUM" is null?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-commons

I keep trying to run my code, but when I run it I get the message

```
"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion.atLeast(org.apache.commons.lang3.JavaVersion)" because "org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils.JAVA_SPECIFICATION_VERSION_AS_ENUM" is null"
```

Anyone know how to fix this? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Please provide a full stack trace that shows this happens in `SystemUtils.isJavaVersionAtLeast`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on an old version of lang3 which does not recognize the Java version you are on. More recent versions are trying to dance around the fact that hard crashing when a new java version is released was always rather daft, but more so when a new java release is available every 6 months, but evidently the version of lang3 you have predates this upgrade.

More generally, don't use apache commons libraries unless you have a very pressing need; they are not particularly good API designs. But, if you must, all you really need to do is update your version dep to the most recent. version `3.11` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! By version dep, are you talking about in the pom.xml file? I looked through my file and my whole project for that matter, and couldn't find where I was using that library.

Comment: Yes. It is possible some other library you use, depends on it. There are tools to find all the deps that maven is pulling in; try adding the lang3 dep to your pom, at v 3.11.

Comment: This was the problem, but for me the solution was to upgrade maven-surefire-plugin version.

Comment: can you share the working pom.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading java in enviromental variables %JAVA_HOME% and Path, 1.8 should be enough